# Momentum and Reaction forces

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

When a block, placed on a incline plane, starts sliding down, why does it push the inclined plane backwards even though the net force ($F=mg$) is vertically downwards?

Comment: Can you draw a diagram of what you mean?

Comment: Because there's still a normal force between the block and plane, sure the net *external* force is in the vertical direction, but that's why the horizontal momentum of the system is conserved too.

Answer (score 0):

> When a block, placed on a incline plane, starts sliding down, why does it push the inclined plane backwards even though the net force (F=mg) is vertically downwards?

On the entire system of block plus wedge, there is no net force in the horizontal direction (the horizontal component of the net force is zero). This means momentum in the horizontal direction must be conserved. But, of course, the block gains momentum in the horizontal direction. So, the wedge must gain an equal amount of momentum in the opposite (horizontal) direction.

P.S. The argument does not apply to the vertical direction.